# Haskell - How do you prepend a bytestring with its length in binary?

Tags: haskell, binary, bytestring

I'm in the unfortunate situation where I need to interface with a Java socket API directly in Haskell. The way Java Strings are sent over the wire is with their length is added to the beginning of the string.

For example:

```
\0\0\0\xBHello World
```

is the string "Hello World"

I can get the length of the `ByteString` no problem, but as an `Int`. I can add a `Word32` to the ByteString using Blaze Builder, but I can't find a convenient way to convert the `Int` to `Word32`. Is there some convenience method I can't find to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I was going to make an answer suggesting [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=Int+-%3E+Word32), but the best suggestion it gave was `toEnum` and I don't want to live in the world where `toEnum` is the go-to function for this. =D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert any integral type with [fromIntegral](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3afromIntegral) function.

Comment: also: don't worry about performance--it should be specialized away

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Data.Binary.encode.

```
foo :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
foo s = B.append (encode $ B.length s) s
```